# Simulation Rules - access allowed; Android - access denied

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a rule which executes correctly in Firestore Rules simulation as seen below.

[image: Simulation]

The /config/permissions document is many arrays named X153, X154, X155, etc., which contain UIDs:

[image: config/permissions]

When I attempt this access in Android, I get a PERMISSION_DENIED response.

Code:

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("arcs").document("X153");
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d("FIREBASE", "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("FIREBASE", "No such document");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("FIREBASE", "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

The UID used in simulation is the same as in Android:

[image: firebaseauth]

If I set the rule to authenticate access of the UID directly

- Android permission accepted, returns document.

If I flatten out the config/permissions structure to just key/values, like `X153 : '9iXQBaG3Ycaey4cFUj8tZjhKMaB3'`, and change the rule to

```
match /arcs/{x} {
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == get(/config/permissions).data[x];
}
```

- Android returns PERMISSION DENIED.

Why am I receiving this PERMISSION DENIED response using the rule pictured?

Comment: It might take upto 15 minutes for the rules to publish

Comment: Please edit the question to show exactly the contents of /config/permissions, and also verify that the client app is logged in with a UID that you exepect.

Comment: @ParthBhoiwala the rule was published 30 minutes ago.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have further edited the post with examples.